# Slidedeck project with SharePoint

Tags: office

I want to give our sales team the ability to create custom slidedecks and then show them while on sales visits.  Obviously, they're sales people, so they're not technically savvy.

Just looking for ideas how I might be able to do this or at least something to start with. I was thinking that the slides could even be created aleady, they would just need to pick which slides would be shown and then a URL created dynamically.  Perhaps using query string..... hmm.

Ideas?  Wouldn't need to be power point either.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint's answer to this would be to create a Slide Library. Then sales people can connect to the slide library using PowerPoint and select the desider slides within PowerPoint. If the slides from Slide Library are updated, when people open PowerPoint presentations containing such slides, they will get notification and can automatically update the slides that have been updated.

[More about slide library.](http://office.microsoft.com/serverhelp/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HA010338394&lcid=1033&products=WSSENDUSER&CTT=3)

Other than that you would need to implement custom solution for selecting the slides and generating a presentation of the selected slides. You can then display them just with PowerPoint or perhaps using Office Web Apps so that sales people could use browser to show the slides. They would need network connection to your server in that case, so it might not be convenient in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft pre-sales people have a demo on this using Fast search engine to find Powerpoint files, and drag and drop slide to dynamically create a new one.

It looks really good, but you'll need to do some development to built it yourself.